# Hibernate @JoinColumn insertable=false doesn't work (duplicate column name)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem in creating some tables with hibernate hdd2auto. Using composed foreign keys it's necessary to indicate when a @ManyToOne relationship on a field which is part of the key should be ignored when updating/creating table. 
Even if I put these settings the results in the logs is the following:

```
2013-07-19 11:44:11 ERROR [hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:235] - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table `ActionLocale` (`ActionId` integer not null, `LanguageId` integer not null, `ActionName` varchar(255), ActionId integer, LanguageId integer, primary key (`ActionId`, `LanguageId`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
2013-07-19 11:44:11 ERROR [hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate:236] - Duplicate column name 'ActionId'
```

As you can see the ActionId column is declared twice in the query! Why??

These are my classes.

Embeddable key:

```
@Embeddable
public class ActionLocalePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ActionId")
    private int actionId;

    @Column(name="LanguageId")
    private int languageId;
```

Class Table:

```
@Entity
public class ActionLocale implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ActionLocalePK id;

    @Column(name="ActionName")
    private String actionName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Action
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ActionId",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Action action;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Language
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LanguageId",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Language language;
```

In the hibernate.cfg.xml I set:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Update the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

I'm using MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31 on Ubuntu. Hibernate version is 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`. You should use the [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation. Or even better, forget about composite IDs, and use a single-column, auto-generated ID instead.

Comment: Can you explain why we shouldn't be using insertable and updatable ? Can you help with this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771892/column-insertable-updateble-dont-go-well-with-spring-jpa

Comment: Because the documented way of having associations mapped to ID columns is to use MapsId.

Answer (score 0):

insertable=false and updatable=false will ignore while saving records. First you should create your table manually then use it. (OR) try to use @transient(Not tested).